# Functional dependence on optional arguments in python

Tags: python, plot, optional-parameters

I am writing some plotting routines in python.  At present I can a function with some parameters and the plot function decides the best x-axis and y-axis scale to use.  Is there a way for me to modify my function definition such that if I provide two extra arguments, say in the form of two lists:

```
xrange=[-10,10] & yrange[0,10]
```

i.e. the function call would be MyPlot([Usual stuff], xrange, yrange) and the plot would know to use xrange and yrange but when I didn't include these additional arguments i.e. my function call was simply MyPlot([Usual stuff]) the function would carry on automatically deciding my scale?
Cheers,
Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your function like this

```
MyPlot([Usual stuff], xrange = None, yrange = None):
   if xrange != None and yrange != None:
       do special stuff
   else:
       ordinary stuff
```

Now, `xrange` and `yrange` accept `None` as default parameters. So, that you can ignore them while calling them. If those parameters are ignored, by default `None` will be assigned to those variables.

Comment: Would these be considered 'positional arguments'?
i.e. if I were to call MyPlot([Usual], [0,10]) would that assume the scale I wanted to set was x or y?  Or should I actually be calling the new function as MyPlot([Usual], yrange=[0,10]) for example?

Comment: Also having built a quick implementation as you suggested shouldn't the conditional statement be like :
if xrange != 'None ...
I get errors if I dont include the inverted commas

Comment: @JackMedley Please edit your question with the latest code which you have.